# Variable with same name as keyword

Tags: naming-conventions, naming, conventions

Is there a good way to create a variable, function, class, etc. with the same name as a keyword?

What I usually see (and follow myself) is using slightly different names. For example, using `clazz` or `Class` instead of `class`.

But using a different name than what is desired feels very hacky and can sometimes be confusing.

In C#, you can use the `@` operator:

```
int @class = 0;
```

However, I'm unaware of equivalents in other popular languages. Are there any?

If not, are there workarounds?
Or are there at least naming conventions to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the word *class* as example I think the best option is to either find a synonym, like *kind* or *category*, or add a contextual word to the identifier, e.g. *priceClass* or *classKind*. Some words can also be abbreviated, so if *function* is a keyword you could use the identifier *func*.

Some programming languages avoid this problem altogether by using upper case keywords or have keywords with special syntax. The advantage with this approach is also that new keywords can be added to the language without invalidating existing code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this is to use a slightly different name as you mentioned, such as appending an underscore or using a similar name. While this may feel hacky or less than ideal, it is a common and accepted practice in many programming communities.

However, in some programming languages, such as C#, it is possible to use the "@" symbol as a prefix to the reserved keyword to use it as a valid identifier. For example, you can create a variable with the name "class" in C# by using the "@" prefix like this: "@class = new MyClass();".

Comment: Smells like ChatGPT...

Comment: @ZachJoseph Hmm. The HuggingFace ChatGPT detector gives only a 15% probability that it is AI generated.